# send/stream dynamic tarball on the fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stream, compression, tar

I have a list of let say 3 files (`/tmp/a.gz`, `/tmp/b.gz`, `/tmp/c.gz`). I would like to tar those files into a tarball and send it to the user.

The problem is that those files are quite large, and I do not want to first create a tar file, then send it, and delete it afterwards.

How could I create and send the tar file on the fly without saving it on HDD, or RAM?

In the controller, `send_data` should be the right method, but I currently do not know how to create such a tarball stream object.

#### update 1

I tried something like this

```rb
# in my controller
command = "tar -C /tmp -cf - a.gz b.gz c.gz | cat"
send_data `#{command }`, type: 'application/x-tar', disposition: 'attachment', filename: 'file_name.tar'
```

I added the `| cat`  to get rid of the tar error message

```sh
tar: Refusing to write archive contents to terminal (missing -f option?)
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

It works, but the problem is that the tar gets loaded into the RAM first.

#### update 2

I added `include ActionController::Live` to my controller and tried to stream the data, but still, the result gets first loaded to RAM

```rb
def download
  filename = "some.tar"
  disposition = ActionDispatch::Http::ContentDisposition.format(disposition: "attachment", filename: filename)
  response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = disposition
  response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-tar"
  response.headers.delete("Content-Length")
  response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache"
  response.headers["Last-Modified"] = Time.now.httpdate.to_s
  response.headers["X-Accel-Buffering"] = "no"
  command = "tar -C /tmp -cf - a.gz b.gz c.gz | cat"
  response.stream.write open("|#{command}").read
ensure
  response.stream.close
end
```

Comment: This [gist](https://gist.github.com/sinisterchipmunk/1335041) or the [`minitar` gem](https://github.com/halostatue/minitar) both seem to provide viable examples for in memory tarball creation however "those files are quite large" might cause issues here.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I cannot load the tarball to the RAM first. Because it is just an internal app, the network speed is not an issue at all.

Comment: To my knowledge (which is extremely limited in this space) a compression algorithm is going to need the contents of the file to determine the best fit pattern for compression, and there is really no way to do this a bit, a byte, or a chunk at a time and even if you could potentially pass this data through a compression stream like this I would be extremely concerned about data corruption upon reassembly. Based on the fact that you cannot store the file contents somewhere (disk or memory) to be evaluated contextually you may not be able to accomplish your goal at all.

Comment: That being said I added the tags for [tag:tar] and [tag:compression] hopefully someone that has a far better understanding than I do can help or at least provide a more comprehensive explanation as to why/how this is or is not possible.